# Digital Signature Verification failed using SHA256withRSA in Python

Tags: hash, cryptography, public-key, xml-signature, rsa-sha256

I am trying to validate the digital signature with given certificate files for the offline aadhaar KYC verification application.

This instruction is given in the documentation for the verification.

Aadhaar Paperless Offline e-KYC when downloaded has the following XML :

```
<OKY v=""n=""r=""i=""d=""e=""m=""g=""a=""s="" />
```

XSD for the above xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schemaxmlns:xs="http: www.w3.org="" 2001="" xmlschema"="" attributeformdefault="unqualified" elementformdefault="qualified" targetnamespace="http://www.uidai.gov.in/offlinePaperlesseKYC/1.0">
<xs:element name="OKY">
<xs:complextype>
<xs:attribute name="v" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="n" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="i" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="e" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="m" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="g" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="r" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="s" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complextype>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

> 1. Read the entire XML and separate the s=”xxxx” tag from it.
> 2. Use a signature validation algorithm leveraging “SHA256withRSA” based hashing and encryption technique
> 3. Signature value present in “s” tag, remaining XML (without "s" tag) and UIDAI public key (available here.) is to be fed to the algorithm to validate the digital signature.

**Sample C# code snippets provided by the organization. (PS :which is also not working**)

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml;

namespace test
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // link -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aSv3HJUFf5_42Z-FqpdVHEk5b3VA3T3D/view


        string XMLFilePath = "offlineaadhaar.xml"; //Get the XML file

// link -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FW4ciIhZqJuelOcGF2x6VaBCSDO9J-gM/view


string KeyFilePath = "okyc-publickey.cer"; //Get the public key certificate file

        XmlDocument ObjXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        ObjXmlDocument.Load(XMLFilePath); //Load the XML
        XmlAttributeCollection SignatureElement = ObjXmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes; //Get the all XML attribute
        string SignatureValue = SignatureElement.GetNamedItem("s").InnerXml; // Get Signature value

        SignatureElement.RemoveNamedItem("s");//Remove the signature "s" attribute from XML and get the new XML to validate

        /*----------------Read and parse the public key as string-----------------------*/
        X509Certificate2 ObjX509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(KeyFilePath, "public"); //Initialize the public ket certificate file

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate objX509Certificate;
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser objX509CertificateParser = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();

        objX509Certificate = objX509CertificateParser.ReadCertificate(ObjX509Certificate2.GetRawCertData());
        /*----------------End-----------------------*/

        /* Init alg */
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ISigner signer = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");

        /* Populate key */
        signer.Init(false, objX509Certificate.GetPublicKey());

        /* Get the signature into bytes */
        var expectedSig = Convert.FromBase64String(SignatureValue);

        /* Get the bytes to be signed from the string */
        var msgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ObjXmlDocument.InnerXml);


        /* Calculate the signature and see if it matches */
        signer.BlockUpdate(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        bool Flag = signer.VerifySignature(expectedSig);            
        if (Flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XML Validate Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XML Validation Failed");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to implement in Python and getting the XML validation failed. I am not sure if the certificate file is wrong or there is some bug on my code.

Here is my Python Code :

```
import xml
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import OpenSSL
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP

xmlDoc = open('adhar.xml', 'r').read()
Tr = etree.XML(xmlDoc)
Tr.keys()
# ['s', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'm', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'v']

sign = Tr.get('s')
len(sign)
# 344

del Tr.attrib['s']

from M2Crypto import X509

x509 =X509.load_cert('ekyc_public_key.cer')
#x509 =X509.load_cert(cert4)
rsa = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
pubkey = EVP.PKey()
pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)

xmlstr = etree.tostring(Tr, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
#rstr=str(xmlstr)[45:][:-1]
#rstr = rstr.encode(encoding='utf-8')


# if you need a different digest than the default 'sha1':
pubkey.reset_context(md='sha256')
pubkey.verify_init()

# hashlib.sha256(message_without_sign).digest()
pubkey.verify_update(xmlstr)
if(pubkey.verify_final(b64decode(sign)) != 1):
    print('Digital Signeture not validated')
else: 
    print('Digital Signeture validated')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description in the question is not enough to completely specify signature generation / verification. Clarification of the protocol is certainly required; it's probably best to request a formalized description. It's not for nothing that XML digsig has been specified; you need a standardized canonicalization, character set etc. In the end, the signature is calculated over bytes, not over XML / text.

`"SHA256withRSA"` is not a signature algorithm; it's the (rather bad) Java name for the PKCS#1 v1.5 signature scheme.

These are not good signs; you should ask if the protocol has been verified by an expert.

Comment: What does `ObjXmlDocument.InnerXml` look like in a text editor / hex editor?

Comment: `<OKV v="1"  n=""  i="imagedata"  d="10121993" e="hashcode" m="hashcode"  g="m"  a="something" r="*******51"  s="VFKxVswVqlPDYOnp7rHUTtLVR3/NQN/p1dI61s1KSy102OgRI5YbXLj9Ng8Cy1fo6a5S62d0NldczYpztM5/E8Z6YUhtknhdVLD24fPijrFoUEqVC2S2fr8FUsCdVXNJEYd2v+UZ2grGYYi68rslaLO7z8SChoedsupRj2F1mwRyrof4u6kdAK5BxvubHPlEZ34Gv3ivuyJnJAKEyDkoymlm2GOAnaLUIxN5vdyBANZMOv9geH2poFOdUGVvOjDbpTPBF3Y5ADosYQYoErsONJ68x3iJsiZcG6dw1gPIW5J3B+X2vgXtFbF9xjFs7rZV9jk7Q8bJos5W8JuVjwV37g=="/>`

Comment: It looks like this with the signature value inside it.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's not what I asked, was it?

Comment: Thanks my issue has been solved. My code was right but the format given in the documentation wasn't enough. That's why it keeps invalided.

Comment: Sorry for that, I keep it in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @ChinmayDas can you please mention what format you have used?

Comment: @ChinmayDas I am waiting for your reply, iI am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @dtb305 which format you are referring ?